# Unique url for each step of multi-step form in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, router

So I have a `SignUp Page` in my website built with `Angular2-Typescript`. And this is a single component containing different steps/wiz-steps of signup. It looks like below,

[image]

I am simply making use of  `ng-if/ng-show/ng-hide` method's to move on to next steps. But the url for all these steps remain the same like `http://mysite/signup`.

But I want a unique url for each steps,something like,
`http://mysite/signup/step1`, `http://mysite/signup/step2`, and so on..

What is the best way to achieve this, without making much changes to the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take profit of child routes to perform that.

#### Suggestion :

1- In your route configuration, define the signup route as below :

```
 {
    path: 'signup',
    children: [
      { 
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/step1',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }, 
      {
        path: ':step',
        component: SignUpComponent
      }
    ]
  },
```

where `:step` is a path variable (Param) which you can make correspond to a typescript `Enum`.

```
export type SignUpStepEnum = "step1" | "step2" | "step3";

export const SignUpStepEnum {
   STEP1: <SignUpStepEnum>"step1",
   STEP2: <SignUpStepEnum>"step2",,
   STEP3: <SignUpStepEnum>"step3",
}
```

And in your `SignUpComponent`, subscribing on the params and displaying the step according of the enum value using a `ngSwitch`.

Example :

```
currentStep: SignUpStepEnum;

this.route.params.subscribe((params: { step: string }) => {
 this.currentStep = SignUpStepEnum[params.step];

if(!this.currentStep) {
//handle error when user is entering an incorrect step.
}
```

And in your view,

```
<div [ngSwitch]="currentStep">
        <step1 *ngSwitchCase="SignUpStepEnum.STEP1"></step1>
        <step2 *ngSwitchCase="SignUpStepEnum.STEP2"></step2>
        <step3 *ngSwitchCase="SignUpStepEnum.STEP3"></step3>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer..
But 

`this.route.params.subscribe((params: { step: string }) => {
      this.currentStep = SignUpStepEnum[params.step];
    });` 

Doesn't seem to work.

It doesn't detect /step1 to /step2 change

Comment: I edited my answer to define the enum as new type with strings. It should  work now. Make sure of case sensitivity.

Comment: No, sorry I meant, 

`this.route.params.subscribe((params: { step: string }) => {
      console.log("hey got one!!")
    });`

In this the text "hey got one!!" doesn't log on url change from ../step1 to ../step2

Comment: route is an `ActivatedRoute` instance ? Would you please give us your route configuration

Comment: Yes route is an ActivatedRoute instance